# Creating a JSON array from PHP and sending a GET request via JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm pulling data from Google Calendar events and wanting to display it in my HTML markup. I've got the data being pulled successfully from Google and thought I was passing it into and array the proper way and encoding into JSON. I was also able to make the GET request via JQuery and confirmed it by checking the console to see if it was received. The problem was trying to display it in the HTML markup. 
But, after further debugging, it seems my JSON array isn't correct. Almost as if it duplicates itself everytime it looks for more data from Google.
Here is my code:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/json');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


include('google-api-php-client-master/autoload.php'); 


date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

//TELL GOOGLE WHAT WE'RE DOING
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("My Calendar");
$client->setDeveloperKey('my_api_key');
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

$calendarId = 'my_calendar_id';
//TELL GOOGLE HOW WE WANT THE EVENTS
$params = array(
    'singleEvents' => true, //CAN'T USE TIME MIN WITHOUT THIS, IT SAYS TO TREAT RECURRING EVENTS AS SINGLE EVENTS
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'timeMin' => date(DateTime::ATOM),//ONLY PULL EVENTS STARTING TODAY

);
$events = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId, $params);



$count = 0; 
$items_to_show = 3; 
$data = array();


    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) 
    { 
        if($count <= $items_to_show) 
        {
            //Convert date to month and day

             $eventDateStr = $event->start->dateTime;
             if(empty($eventDateStr))
             {
                 // it's an all day event
                 $eventDateStr = $event->start->date;
             }

             $temp_timezone = $event->start->timeZone;

             if (!empty($temp_timezone)) 
             {
                $timezone = new DateTimeZone($temp_timezone); //GET THE TIME ZONE
             } 
             else 
             { 
                $timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"); //Set your default timezone in case your events don't have one
             }

             if ($count >= $items_to_show) 
             {
                break;
             }


             $eventdate = new DateTime($eventDateStr,$timezone);

             $data[$count]['newmonth'] = $eventdate->format("M");
             $data[$count]['newday'] = $eventdate->format("j");
             $data[$count]['newtime'] = $eventdate->format("g:i A");

             echo json_encode($data);


             ++$count; //INCREASE COUNT AND START AGAIN. 

        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my JSON array (there are only 3 events on the calendar) but it looks like it duplicates or resets everytime it looks for more:

```
[{"newmonth":"Jan","newday":"16","newtime":"3:00 PM"}][{"newmonth":"Jan","newday":"16","newtime":"3:00 PM"},{"newmonth":"Jan","newday":"17","newtime":"2:00 PM"}][{"newmonth":"Jan","newday":"16","newtime":"3:00 PM"},{"newmonth":"Jan","newday":"17","newtime":"2:00 PM"},{"newmonth":"Jan","newday":"18","newtime":"3:00 AM"}]
```

Here is my JQuery that I want to display in the HTML automatically:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    function load() 
    {

        $.ajax
        ({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'googlesidebar.php',
            // data: {key: 'value'},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) 
            {
                console.debug(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
                {
                    $('.newmonth').append(data[i].newmonth),
                    $('.newday').append(data[i].newday),
                    $('.newtime').append(data[i].newtime)
                };

                setTimeout(load, 5000);
            },
            error: function(data) 
            {
                //called when there is an error
                console.log(data.message);
            }
        });
    };

    load();
});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="newmonth"></div>
<div class="newday"></div>
<div class="newtime"></div>

<footer>

</footer>



<script src="ajax.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to output data `$data` only once with `json_encode`, otherwise it has a wrong syntax. Put it at the end of your code and it should work.

Comment: OMG thank you! It's always the little things!